# ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found Even though the module has been installed

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anaconda

I installed `scikit-learn` using `pip` in an Anaconda env. I tried to do the following importations for a machine learning project

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate, train_test_split
from sklearn import preprocessing, svm
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
```

and I have been constantly getting an error

```
File "C:\python test\regressiontesting.py", line 5, in <module>
    from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate, train_test_split

File "C:\Users\Faizan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 75, in <module>
    from .utils._show_versions import show_versions

File "C:\Users\Faizan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_show_versions.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ._openmp_helpers import _openmp_parallelism_enabled

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _openmp_helpers: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: You say you are using Anaconda, but the error shows that you are loading modules from a different local installation of Python. Conda can have unpredictable behavior if you have other Python instances on `PATH` or `PYTHONPATH`. Make sure these are removed. Also, Conda is rather finicky when mixing with `pip` - it is best to always install through Conda when available (see "[*Using Pip in a Conda Environment*](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/)").

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what version of `numpy` you are using, I would first try downgrading Python to 3.7.

I advise you that next time you ask a question you also provide the version of the package you are using.

You can usually find the version of a package as simple as:

```
>> import numpy
>> print(numpy.__version__)
```

Furthermore, don't hesitate to use backticks to pretty format the code snippets you are pasting, so that they are more readable. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)